# java boolean method return statement

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return

I'm trying to program a game, and I'm making methods to check the different sides of a player for terrain. I'm using a boolean method, but netbeans is telling me I don't have a return statement.

```
public boolean checkTerrainDown(Level levelToCheck){
    for(Terrain terrainToCheck: levelToCheck.levelTerrain){
        if(y+h<terrainToCheck.getY()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When your method has to return something you need to provide return statement for every possible execution path that can be taken.

Comment: It's a good practice to only have an only return statement! by the way , you didn't have to make a `for` for what you are doing.. you only are asking for the first element.. besides use `return y+h < terraintoCheck.getY();`

Comment: @nachokk: No, it's really not. It's a good practice to make your code as clear as possible. Sometimes that means one return statement - sometimes it means multiple ones.

Comment: @JonSkeet you got it right, it's a personal decission that i don't like multiple returns most of the times, i think i only use multiple returns for the "easy cases" but a readable clean code is what we have to point :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if there is no `Terrain` to check?  Then the body of the `for` loop never gets executed.  You have no `return` statement after the `for` loop to account for this case.  What would you have Java return in this case?

Place a `return` statement after the `for` loop to handle the case in which there's no `Terrain` in the `Level`'s `levelTerrain`.  That way, every possible case of execution will `return` something.

Answer (score 1):

if the `for loop` doesn't executed then there is no return statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean checkTerrainDown(Level levelToCheck){
        //add this line
        boolean mark = false;
    for(Terrain terrainToCheck: levelToCheck.levelTerrain){
        if(y+h<terrainToCheck.getY()){
                //add this line,remove this //return true;
            mark = true;
            //add this line
            break;
        }
        //else{
            //return false;
        //}
    }
    //add this line
    return mark;
}
```